# Sunspot - Searching in multiple date ranges

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, model, sunspot, sunspot-rails

Here's my problem, I'll try to be concise.

I have a model `Course` that `has_many` `Planning`.
A `Planning` has a `start_date` and an `end_date`.

I want to retrieve (with sunspot) all the `Courses` that have a particular planning  between a given `start_date` and an `end_date`.

The problem is that if I store in the model `Course` :

```
searchable do
  date :start_date, multiple: true do
    plannings.map(&:start_date)
  end

  date :end_date, multiple: true do
    plannings.map(&:end_date)
  end
  ...
end
```

I loose the fact that `start_date` and `end_date` are couples.

Is there a way / trick to store ranges?

Comment: how do you search date range in controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have almost the same problem, in my case start_date and end_date wasn't really a date, just a year (integer), solve it with multiple value fields  as range:

```
searchable do
  date :course_date, multiple: true do
    plannings.map{|p| (p.start_date..p.end_date).to_a}
  end
  ...
end
```

so course_date contain all years when courses going. If you have 2001-2003 and 2005-2007(2001, 2002, 2003, 2005, 2006, 2007) and search with equal_to.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility would be to make your query in two times. First find the plannings, then find the courses restricting courses by ID.

Maybe not a very optimised one, but why try to optimize to soon...

Or to index hours with a function:

```
def happens_between_8_and_9
  return true if start_date > 8..
end

searchable do
  boolean :happens_between_8_and_9
  boolean :happens_between_9_and_10
end
```

```

Comment: I'll try that!
I can't do the second proposition as I'm dealing with dates and not time. But interesting trick!